# why stylesheets are in comments?

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style8 {font-size: 12px; color: #333333; }
.style9 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style12 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; }
.style13 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #0066FF; }
.style14 {
    color: #0043A8;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.style15 {color: #FFFFFF}
.style16 {color: #990000}
.style18 {color: #990000; font-size: 12px; }
.style20 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #575757; }
-->
</style>
```

above stylesheet is enclosed in `<!-- -->` html comments tag. why? I can't get valid explanation for this; some tutorials do this while some doesn't (like http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp which I think is very valid reference)

Comment: w3schools is not a very good reference, they are known of adding crappy content all the time. Using w3schools as a reference should be seen as "use at your own risk". For more info: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's not a comment... it's a way to hide such text block from old browsers parser (mainly IE6-)

It's the same as using the [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) technique on the `<script>` tag... to **protect bad parsing of the data** from really weird engines (mainly IE) :)

though the **correct way** would be using:

## for styles

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    body { color: yellow; }     
/*]]>*/
</style>
```

## for scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(function() { ... });
//]]>
</script>
```

using `CDATA` in both cases is the **correct and safe way**, the *comment* way it's just a trick to accomplish the same end result.

---

Now, regarding your **I think is very valid reference** when pointing out W3Schools, have a look at this:

> http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I really stop using w3schools... but "dang" Google keeps puttin' those link right on top... grrr!

Comment: i usally go with the `-w3schools` when searching the Googles for help :)

Comment: good idea, but try to see the results with `html` and `-w3schools html` ... for me, they removed the *w3validator* as well :/

Comment: @limelights I usually go with visual filtering. Usually, Stack overflow and MDN stick quite close to the top, even without explicit hints. IF SO sticks to the top by itself, it's a sign of a great answer.

Comment: @balexandre i never append more than one `-` criteria. @jandvorak we meet again. Mr. Hungarian.

Answer (score 2):

It is an antiquated method of hiding content from browsers who are older than the standard that introduced `<style>` or `<script>` tags.

There is no valid use for such a habit anymore and in fact will cause more problems than it fixes.

Unless you are developing a website for peolpe living in the 1990's (like the editors at w3schools)... don't do it!

Answer (score 1):

This is done to avoid displaying the script content in some (old) browsers which don't know about `<style>` markup. See [this](http://lachy.id.au/log/2005/05/script-comments).

Comment: why do you mention `<script>` while he asked regarding `<style>`?

Comment: Sorry, mistyping :) In fact, that occurs on scripts, too (maybe mostly).

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack for older browsers that didn't support CSS/style tag... See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.5

Answer (score 0):

Few browsers consider the `non-HTML` codes as plain text. This comment is used to guide that browser i.e the code is commented so that `browsers` will not display it as html output.